CXX1429: error when building with cmake using app\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [prefab] failed while executing
I was trying to build android vulkan app from this guide
Whenever I try to build, execution error occurred in
"app\build\intermediates\cxx\Debug\1k4v2e55\logs\arm64-v8a\prefab_command.bat" file.
When I take a look at the batch script, It seems because of double quoting, used with escape character, caret(^). When I wrap this one more double quoting, then the script seemed to work well when I run it locally.
But as this script is generated during Gradle Sync, so I wonder how to workaround this.
Is there anybody experienced the same problem ??
Here's the script.
@echo off
"C:\\Program Files\\Android\\Android Studio\\jbr\\bin\\java" ^
  --class-path ^
  "C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\AndroidGradleCache\\caches\\modules-2\\files-2.1\\com.google.prefab\\cli\\2.1.0\\aa32fec809c44fa531f01dcfb739b5b3304d3050\\cli-2.1.0-all.jar" ^
  com.google.prefab.cli.AppKt ^
  --build-system ^
  cmake ^
  --platform ^
  android ^
  --abi ^
  arm64-v8a ^
  --os-version ^
  30 ^
  --stl ^
  c++_shared ^
  --ndk-version ^
  25 ^
  --output ^
  "C:\\Users\\<UserName>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\agp-prefab-staging173918899557672872\\staged-cli-output" ^
  "C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\AndroidGradleCache\\caches\\8.9\\transforms\\d32a77d7e7bb7e9756a33ac5cd5bf668\\transformed\\jetified-games-activity-4.0.0-alpha01\\prefab"


And here's the stderr. It seems like cmd.exe couldn't parse the script correctly, maybe because of caret(^)(?).
'\Program'은(는) 내부 또는 외부 명령, 실행할 수 있는 프로그램, 또는
배치 파일이 아닙니다.
'class-path'은(는) 내부 또는 외부 명령, 실행할 수 있는 프로그램, 또는
배치 파일이 아닙니다.
'm.google.prefab.cli.AppKt'은(는) 내부 또는 외부 명령, 실행할 수 있는 프로그램, 또는
배치 파일이 아닙니다.
'"C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\AndroidGradleCache\\caches\\8.9\\transforms\\d32a77d7e7bb7e9756a33ac5cd5bf668\\transformed\\jetified-games-activity-4.0.0-alpha01\\prefab"'은(는) 내부 또는 외부 명령, 실행할 수 있는 프로그램, 또는
배치 파일이 아닙니다.


OS: Windows 11 Pro, 22H2, 22621.2861
SDK: 34
NDK: 25.2.9519653
CMake: 3.22.1
Dependencies: I tried games-activity:2.0.0, 3.0.0, 4.0.0

Changing NDK, CMake versions
Changing games-activity version
Changing the script manually and run it (wrapping one more double quotes)


It was because of korean letter in file path: C:\Users\..
It seems that Android Studio cannot recognize any non-ascii character.
I made a new User, username with alphabets, and give admin authority, and setup gradle in this path.
Hope to save time for someone who faces this problem..
